# compiling ffmpeg Ubuntu 16

Tags: ffmpeg, build, compilation, ubuntu-16.04

I am new on stackowerflow.

I need a advice :)
I have tried compile ffmpeg 2.8.15 from source under Ubuntu 16 LTS. I need compile it for one SDK, I can't use ffmpeg from repository. I compiled ffmpeg successfully. But I have got issues with my specify SDK, when I try compile my code with SDK:

```
SDK.so: undefined reference to `av_rescale_q@LIBAVUTIL_FFMPEG_54'
```

I suppose that issues are in symbols name. I tried read symbols with

```
readelf -s libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54
```

I get in my compiled ffmpeg something like this

```
   158: 0000000000024170    55 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 av_rescale_q@@LIBAVUTIL_54
```

I tried this with libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54 from repository and i get

```
   158: 0000000000024170    55 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 av_rescale_q@@LIBAVUTIL_FFMPEG_54
```

I suppose that I need add a suffix "FFMPEG" to symbols name.
I use this configuration for build ffmpeg, it same as configuration of build from repository :

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
```

Could you help how add suffix "-ffmpeg" to symbols name?
Thanks

Best Regard

retepik

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, mayby it will usefull for anotherone. I downloaded ubuntu developer source of ffmpeg with following command on ubuntu 16 and compiled on ubuntu 18 :

`apt-get source ffmpeg`

Now I have got correct symbols in libavxxx